# Calling the __init__ function using map

Tags: python, constructor

I would like to construct a list of objects from a list of parameters, by calling `__init__` for each element in the list. Is it possible to do that?
Here is an example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,x ):
        self.x = x

X = [1,2,3]

ob1 = [Foo(x) for x in X]
# works!

ob2 = map(Foo.__init__, X)
does not work
```

Comment: You could do `list(map(Foo, X))`. Or in Python 2: `map(Foo, X)`, since the Python 2 `map` returns a list instead of an iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No reason to specify `__init__`; that is never called explicitly. Just `map(Foo, X)` is fine.